# C - expected expression before '{' token

Tags: c

Can anyone please point out why I get the `syntax error: expected expression before '{' token`in

```
T[SIZE] = {NULL};
```

in the code segment below?
Thanks.

```
typedef struct SetObject{
    int key;
    struct SetObject *prev;
    struct SetObject *next;
} Node;

Node *T[SIZE]; //global variable

void initT(void) {
    T[SIZE] = {NULL};
}
```

Comment: On which line do you get that error?

Comment: why do you have { } around NULL?

Comment: @Gabriel: Hmm that resolves. I put {} since it was an array. What's the reason why it is omitted in this initialization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To assign a pointer value to an array element, use:

```
T[SIZE] = NULL;
```

The curly brackets around `NULL` are not needed.

The second problem is that `SIZE` is an *invalid* index into the `T` array. The valid indexes range from `0` through `SIZE-1`. Assigning to `T[SIZE]` will lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes, that would set the last element of the `T` array to `NULL`. However, from your comments it seems that you may want to set the contents of the *whole* array at once. You can do that when the array is *defined*, as in `Node *T[SIZE] = {NULL};`, but you can't do that using the `{NULL}` syntax anywhere else. You could use `memset()` or equivalent, though.

Comment: Yeah that is what I am doing actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If T is an array of pointers to T, then T[index] is a pointer to T, and you should write:

```
T[index] = NULL;
```

(so no curly braces around NULL).

But there is more wrong with your code.  T is a global variable, an array with SIZE elements.
This means that the first element has index 0, and the last one has index SIZE-1.  So writing `T[SIZE] = NULL;` is actually incorrect, and might crash your application.

What is it that you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Thanks. I am initializing the array T to NULL (all elements).